# Nomad and Waypoint cannot launch more than 2 jobs

Tags: nomad, waypoint

I'am currently tryng to deploy several **db** on **Nomad cluster**.
**Test - dev - qa - ppd**
I'am using waypoint with var files to automatise deploy.
I have strange issue, **I cannot launch** more than **2 db job**, when I launch **new db job** the older 2 jobs disappear and **replaced by new db job** launched previously.

**Waypoint file**

```
# waypoint up -var-file=/opt/waypoint/xx/xx-api/dev/dev.wpvars
project = "xx-db"

# An application to deploy.
app "xx-db" {
    build {
        use "docker" {
            dockerfile = "${path.app}/${var.dockerfile_path}"
        }
        
        
        # Uncomment below to use a remote docker registry to push your built images.
        #
         registry {
           use "docker" {
             #image = "registry.example.com/image"
             image =  "${var.registry_path}/xx-db-${var.env}"
             tag   = "${var.version}"
           }
         }

    }



 # Deploy to Docker
    deploy {
           use "nomad-jobspec" {
      jobspec = templatefile("${path.app}/finess-db.hcl", {
    datacenter = var.datacenter
  env = var.env

          })
    }
    }
}




variable env {
    type = string
    default = ""
}

variable dockerfile_path {
    type = string
    default = "Dockerfile"
}

variable "registry_path" {
    type = string
    default = "registry.repo.proxy-xx-xx.xx.xx.xx.net"
               
}

variable datacenter {
    type = string
    default = "xx"
}

variable "version" {
  type    = string
  default = gitrefpretty()
  env     = ["gitrefpretty()"]
               
}
```

[image: 2 job]

After new job the older test and formation disapper
[image: new job]

```
job "xxx-psqldb-${env}" {
        datacenters = ["xxx"]
        type = "service"
          vault {
          policies = ["xxx"]
          change_mode = "noop"
          }
        update {
                stagger = "30s"
                max_parallel = 1
        }

        group "xxx-psqldb-${env}" {
                count = "1"
                restart {
                        attempts = 3
                        delay = "60s"
                        interval = "1h"
                        mode = "fail"
                }
                network {
                        mode = "host"
                        port "pgsqldb" { to = 5432 }
                }
                task "xxx-psqldb-${env}" {
                        driver = "docker"
                        config {
                                image = "${artifact.image}:${artifact.tag}"
                                ports = [
                                        "pgsqldb"
                                        ]
                                volumes = [
                                    "name=xxxpsqldb${env},io_priority=high,size=5,repl=1:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
                                ]
                                volume_driver = "pxd"

                        }
                        template {
                                data = <<EOH
POSTGRES_USER="{{ with secret "app/xxx/db/admin" }}{{ .Data.data.user }}{{end}}"
POSTGRES_PASSWORD="{{ with secret "app/xxx/db/admin" }}{{ .Data.data.password }}{{end}}"

EOH
                                destination = "secrets/db"
                                env = true
                        }
                        resources {
                                cpu = 256
                                memory = 256
                        }
                        service {
                                name = "xxx-psql-svc-${env}"
                                tags = ["urlprefix-xxx-psql-${env} proto=tcp"]
                                port = "pgsqldb"
                                 check {
                                         name         = "alive"
                                         type         = "tcp"
                                         interval     = "10s"
                                         timeout      = "5s"
                                         port         = "pgsqldb"
                                }

                        }

                }
        }
}
```

**I have this same issue when I launch other job for front app or back app**.

Should I configure something in the cluster ?

Thx for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive encountered similar issue.

TLDR: use `-prune=false`

Explanation

As the [waypoint docs](https://developer.hashicorp.com/waypoint/plugins/nomad#nomad-jobspec-canary-releasemanager) mention:

> ... if -prune=false is not set, Waypoint may delete your job via "pruning" a previous version

Furthermore,that currently locks you to using CLI

> CLI flags are the only way to customize this today

As described [here](https://developer.hashicorp.com/waypoint/docs/lifecycle/release#deployment-pruning)

The issue can be also found on  [hashicorp disuss](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/every-deployment-ends-with-no-allocations-for-job-are-running-third-deployment-prunes-the-job-from-nomad-away).

Answer (score 0):

Just delete files **data.db** and **waypoint-restore.db.lock** resolved issue.

Thx